# How to change Windows 7 default taskbar behaviour for IE8?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, internet-explorer-8

When I left click on the IE8 Logo on the taskbar I want it open a new tab in
the current running instance of internet explorer instead of the peek menu.

Answer (score 2):

Either hit Shift while left clicking or middle click instead.

Comment: +1 didn't know about shift+click.

Comment: That seems to just open a new IE window... not a tab.

Comment: I use the middle click too